# Extract multiple attributes values in XML tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, awk

I have a XML file (`test.xml`) that can be sum up as follow (I filtered it so it will be more readable):

```
<coverage complexity="0" line-rate="0.66" lines-covered="66" lines-valid="100">
    <packages>
        <package complexity="0" line-rate="0.66" name=".">
            <classes>
                <class complexity="0" name="file_a.py" line-rate="0.7674">
                <class complexity="0" name="file_b.py" line-rate="0.2727">
                <class complexity="0" name="file_c.py" line-rate="1">
            </classes>
        </package>
    </packages>
</coverage>
```

For each line, I want to extract both `name` and `line-rate` info, for example output could be:

```
. 0.66
file_a.py 0.7674
file_b.py 0.2727
file_c.py 1
```

Note that I'll like to skip the 1st line since it as no `name` field.

Right now I managed to get that output with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Extract info in lines containing either "<package " or "<class "
linerates=`grep '<package \|<class ' test.xml | awk -F "line-rate=" '{print $2}' | awk -F '"' '{$
names=`grep '<package \|<class ' test.xml | awk -F "name=" '{print $2}' | awk -F '"' '{print $2}$

# Transform to array
linerates=(${linerates// / })
names=(${names// / })

# Print table
for i in "${!names[@]}"
do
        echo ${names[$i]} ${linerates[i]}
done
```

Since the code is quite ugly, I wonder if there is a way to extract those two informations in a more elegant way, let say in one command line / without the need to use a for loop

---

**Edit**

I switch to python and got this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open('test.xml', 'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, 'lxml')

list_ = list(bs_content.find('classes').children)
list_ = list(filter(lambda a: a != '\n', list_))

for c in list_:
    print(c.get('name'), c.get('line-rate'))
```

The output is a bit reduced (but I'm OK with it)

```
file_a.py 0.7674
file_b.py 0.2727
file_c.py 1
```

I am still looking to do it using a single command line but for now I will go with the python version

---

**Edit** (following greybeard's comment)

- I filtered my XML file to remove all unnecessary lines (none of them have attributes `name` nor `line-rate`). E.g of removed lines:

  ```
  <lines>
       <line hits="1" number="1"/>
  </lines>
  ```
- Not much complications my file is generated so the attributes should always be in the same order. Coverage, package and class have more attributes. E.g. for "coverage" also has a timestamp and a version attributes ; "class" has a filename attribute which is the same as `name`

Feel free to ask if I forgot some other information

Comment: You tagged `awk` - decades ago, that would have been my first attempt; I'm confident it still is a good fit - as far as the task is defined above. There may be extensions in the wings, complications like attributes changing position: tell (alt least) as much as necessary for a helpful review.

Comment: Question updated to answer your comment

Comment: Is the actual XML guaranteed to have at most one line-rate/name pair per line, and those two attributes always on the same line as each other?

Comment: It's also worth noting that the XML you posted is malformed, because the `class` tags are not terminated.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your posted example that prevent it from being sanely parsed by XML, including lack of closing tags and lack of a starting `xml` tag. You say that the content is generated: if you generated it, you should try to fix this. Anyway.

```
import re

pat = re.compile('name="(.*?)".*'
                 'line-rate="([0-9.]*)"')

with open('test.xml') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = pat.search(line)
        if match:
            print(match.expand(r'\1 \2'))
```

This makes many assumptions:

- The attributes actually are in the same order every time (in your example, they aren't, despite you saying that they should be)
- The file is guaranteed to have at most one line-rate/name pair per line
- Those two attributes are always on the same line as each other

If all of those conditions are satisfied, the above works.

### Actual XML

If (as it seems you suggested in a now-rolled-back edit) your input can actually be valid XML, then a method that will perform more validation is

```
from xml.sax import parse, ContentHandler

class Handler(ContentHandler):
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        name, rate = attrs.get('name'), attrs.get('line-rate')
        if name and rate:
            print(f'{name} {rate}')

parse('test.xml', Handler())
```

I do not know if it is faster, but it's probably a better idea to do this and halt-and-catch-fire if the XML is malformed, which SAX will do for you.

Comment: Thanks! I made some modifications in the question. Concerning your assumptions they are OK, and it works perfectly ! (I get the reduce output since conditions are not reunite for package attributes to be considered, but I'm OK with that)

Comment: @Nuageux Edited to demonstrate SAX.